# jquery transition not working when transitioning back

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap and Jquery Transit to transform my navbar when it reaches a specific scrollpoint.
Now when I only have the part in the if statement it works fine but i want it to transition back when the user scrolls up. The issue is that as soon as I add the else part, none of the transitions work.
When I refresh below the bottomof_karussel line the navbar "spawns" in it's transformed mode. Any ideas?

Here's a "working" fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/zy6o57un/9/

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
            var bottom_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();
            var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();
            /**Navbar transition**/
            //#region navbartransition
            if(top_of_screen > bottom_of_Karussel){
                //Logo
                $('.navbar-dark .navbar-brand').transition({color: '#cd212a', duration: '1200'});
                //Background
                $('nav').transition({backgroundColor: '#f4f5f0', duration: '1200'/*, border: '2px', borderColor: '#cd212a'*/});
                //active Link
                $('.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active').transition({color: '#cd212a', duration: '1200'});
                 //active Link
                $('.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link').transition({color: '#cd212a', duration: '1200'});
                //inactive Links
                $('.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link').transition({color: '#e89a9f;', duration: '1200'});                    
            }
            else{
              /*  //Logo
                $('.navbar-dark .navbar-brand').transition({color: '#f4f5f0', duration: '1200'});
                //background
                $('nav').transition({backgroundColor: '#cd212a', duration: '1200'});
                //active Link
                $('.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active').transition({color: '#f4f5f0', duration: '1200'});
                 //active Link
                $('.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link').transition({color: '#f4f5f0', duration: '1200'});
                //inactive Links
                $('.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link').transition({color: '#e89a9f;', duration: '1200'});   
                */
            }
```

Comment: It would be better if you add a working demo.

Comment: thanks, i added one

Comment: I think the issue is that you're stacking a giant amount of animations onto the queue by initiating them on every `scroll` event without clearing the previous animations: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpon973b